# How many are telling the truth?

Tags: puzzle

Each person in a group of 5 makes a statement. Alex says ''atleast one of us is lying''. Sar says ''atleast two of us are lying''. Esther says ''atleast four of us are lying''. Gaf says ''all of us are lying''. Krom says ''none of us is lying''. Base on these statements how many persons telling the truth.

Comment: Have you tried solving this yourself? Can all the statements be true?

Comment: This would be more appropriate on puzzling.stackexchange

Answer (score 4):

If Gaf is truthful, then he claims he himself is lying. Therefore Gaf must be lying. We already know of at least one liar, so Alex must be telling the truth and Krom is lying. Gaf and Krom are lying, so Sar is telling the truth. We have identified 2 liars and 2 non-liars. From this we can conclude that the final person, Esther, is lying.

Comment: Beautiful. This is exactly how to attack the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Only two men are telling the truth: Alex and Sar.

Gaf and Grom are surely lying, because Gaf is lying (his assertation is a contradiction) then also Grom is lying. There are at least two liars, hence Alex and Sar are telling the truth. It remains Esther who are surely lying (because you have already found two people who are telling the truth, then there are almost 3 liars)

Comment: how did u arrive at that conclusion Ella?

Comment: @Jean-Claude I do not understand your comment. The question asks for the number telling the truth. The answer explains who is lying and why.

Comment: @almagest It was a comment before edition of the answer. I'll remove it now.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Ah, sorry! I am new to this game (4th day). It is much trickier than it looks - people can revise things and then your comments need adjusting! :(